# sort a dictionary and change the index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, sorting

In my app, I have a dictionary with two array like:

```
NSDictionary *d=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:listOfEvents,@"l",arr_distance,@"d", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",d);


 d =     (
    "353.90",
    "354.68",
    "350.42",
    "1.18"
);
l =     (
            {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
         {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
      {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
      {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           }
); 
}
```

I want to sort the dictionary with first array and when the index changes , the second array index also changed according to it.

Both arrays index are related to each other.

@ABC  your tried code

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:listOfEvents  forKeys:arr_distance];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
        NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *key in sortedArray) {
        [sortedValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:key]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",sortedValues);
```

Result:

{
1.18,2563.91,2563.41,2563.39,350,353,354}

Comment: Can u please explain further ?

Comment: So implement a sorting algorithm and every time you swap an element of a, do the same with B. Or create a new array of indexes {1,2,3,4,0,5}

Comment: but when i want to display both array of index are related to each other like Array a is the distance & array B is other info which come from web.

Comment: Alternatively, try defining a mapping of your favorite kind (e.g. a dictionary) from numbers 8, 2, etc. to triples (x=a, y=f, z=k), (x=r, y=t, z=q).  With that mapping, after ordering the array of numbers, you can build the ordered array of triples by setting the nth triple to be the image of the nth number in the ordered array under the mapping.

Comment: How about instead of defining two arrays with properties that are linked through index, create one class which stores both the double and the string, and store thath in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it,

```
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8", @"2", @"4", nil];
    NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"val1", @"val2", @"val3", nil];//This can be an array of any objects
```

or

```
a = ["353.90", "354.68", "350.42", "1.18"];
b = [{
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
         {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
      {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
           },
      {
        Contestant1 = "Jon jones";
        Contestant2 = "Anderson silva";
       }];
```

Do it like this,

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:b forKeys:a];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [a sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
        return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
    NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *key in sortedArray) {
        [sortedValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:key]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",sortedValues);
```

Comment: What is the issue, because I am able to sort it properly. You might have to change the sort logic if the issue is with sorting. This one is for strings.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are seeing when it is sorted? What my understanding is that when d is sorted, l also should get sorted in the same order, right?

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Because just now I tried and I am getting it sorted in this order, 1.18,
350.42,
353.90,
354.68. Can you update the question with the NSLog statement output  you are getting?

Comment: Tried that too, and I am getting correct output as {1.18,
2563.39,
2563.41,
2563.91}

Comment: Can you print the NSLog of arr_distance before creating dictionary? Members of that array are NSNumbers or NSStrings?

Comment: As per string comparison whatever you are getting is correct, 2563.41 comes before 350 if you compare as string. so you need to compare it as number then right? I have updated my answer. Check with this.

Comment: Use sortedArray and sortedValues.

Comment: I found one problem in your code. when the two distances are same & venue Names are different, then It shows me only first venue Name Two Times.Help me to solve this problem

Comment: @user1673099, The above answer is based on the assumption that key is unique as shown in your question. If there is a chance that it could repeat, you cant use this solution. If you have already posted a different question, I can post a different answer there.

Comment: @user1673099, Posted the answer on your other question. Please check and accept if it works. Sorry for all the confusions.